# How would set a response header X-Frame-Options?

Tags: html, iframe, response, httpresponse

I need help with setting a response header for my site, hosted on Github pages. How would I set the `X-Frame-Options` option to `DENY`? I could use HTML, CSS, JS, or PHP.

I have tried using `<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">` but I got this message in console:

```
X-Frame-Options may only be set via an HTTP header sent along with a document. It may not be set inside <meta>.
```

**UPDATE**

Since I can not edit the headers because my site is hosted on GitHub, is there a way to check if the page is in an iframe and display an image instead of the content?

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

Github pages does not provide any mechanism for customising HTTP response headers (including running server-side code in any programming language).

Comment: is there any other way i can prevent iframes then?